# Is there a way to format a date time object?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-3.5, format

So last week, the way our application worked was that the back-end team was storing dates as a string in YYYY-MM-DD formats. This week, they changed it to be a DateTime object instead of a string. So now I'm just creating a DateTime object from the string value on this particular DateTime control we use.

So basically with our custom control , it was like this:

```
mySearchModelObject.fromDate = myDateRangeControl.Values[0]; //string
mySearchModelObject.toDate = myDateRangeControl.Values[1]; //string
```

Now it's more like this:

```
DateTime fromDate, toDate;
DateTime.Tryparse(myDateRangeControl.Values[0], out fromDate);
DateTime.Tryparse(myDateRangeControl.Values[1], out toDate);

mySearchModelObject.fromDate = fromDate;
mySearchModelObject.toDate = toDate;
```

But searching with the same date range as last week yields different results from the DB.

I'm wondering if it's because our dates were "YYYY-MM-DD" as strings, but now it's getting a date time object in whatever the system's format is + the time itself.

So is there a way to format my DateTime object to still have it in the same YYYY-MM-DD format?

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.TryParseExact and provide "yyyy-MM-dd" as format string.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22

Answer (score 1):

you can do `fromDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` to have a date formatted as YYYY-MM-DD

see msdn on [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) datetime format

see demo https://dotnetfiddle.net/NZz0HG

also if `mySearchModelObject.fromDate` is of type object, you can assign a DateTime or a string, no compiler warnings/error. 
But when is used, maybe with `mySearchModelObject.fromDate.ToString()` you get a different result, before was '2014-12-31' and now `12/31/2014 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: I think there might have been a misunderstand; the `mySearchModelObject` fields are `DateTime` now, so converting it to a string like I was before is invalid.

Comment: ah ok, btw dont use TryParse without checking result code.
Use ``Parse`` (throw exception if cannot be parsed) otherwise you dont know if parse is ok or not (and fromDate is default date)

Comment: I can't copy paste from my remote connection to my actual PC where I made this post, it's more along the lines of IF (tryParse...) { assign values }. Left it just because it's shorter to type. Thanks though :)